# excel pivot table - count appearance of certan value in column

Tags: excel, pivot-table

let's say i have folowing data for my excel pivot table:

`country_id   user_id   answer
 ----------   -------   ------
    1           1         Y 
    1           2         Y 
    2           3         N
    2           4         Y
    3           5         N`

i would like to count how many "Y" i have per country.
If i put "answer" in Values as "Count of answer" i get 1 for each row. How can i count only "Y" answers?

so the result will be:

`country_id   answerY
-----------   -------
    1           2
    2           1
    3           0`

br
Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution similar to @pkg.  Add one more column in your data and call it "answerY" with the formula:

```
=IF(C4="Y",1,0)
```

or, if your data is in a table:

```
=IF([@answer]="Y",1,0)
```

Now, set up your pivot table as follows:

```
Row lables:  country
Values: answerY (sum)
```

Ordinarily I'd say to add a calculated field in a pivot table, but calculated fields work off of the aggregate values, and I can't think of a way to do this with a straight pivot table.

If you have the ability to use PowerPivot, you could create a custom column or a Dax expression that would handle this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do that in a pivot table, but if you would like to do it outside of a pivot table you could make a couple of columns with these formulas:

```
Column D:
=IF(C2="Y",1,0)*A2

Column E:
=COUNTIF(D$2:D$6,B2)
```

This assumes that all user IDs are unique and sequential, and D$6 needs to be replaced with whatever is the last value in the column. Column E will have the values you described as answerY.